# Use cases for Object.create(null)

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I understand that using `Object.create(null)` creates an object which has no `proto` property (i.e. `Object.getPrototypeOf(  myObj  ) === null`) but can someone help me understand what are some of the use cases for this?

In other words, why would you want to create an object that is completely empty (i.e. doesn't inherit any methods from `Object.prototype`)?

Comment: It's not really that useful, but in some cases where stuff have been added to the prototype chain, you might not want that in your object. In other cases, you'd like to use keys such as `valueOf` or `toString`, but then you have a problem, as they are already inherited from `Object`, unless you create an object that does not inherit those properties etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In very rare instances where something may have been added to `Object.prototype`

```
Object.prototype.bar = 'bar';
```

It may be better to create an *Object* with `Object.create(null)` as it won't inherit this, consider

```
({}).bar;                // bar
// vs
Object.create(null).bar; // undefined
```

This means you don't have to worry for example if you've used a `for..in` loop

Furthermore, you can make it so you fail `instanceof` tests

```
Object.create(null) instanceof Object; // false
```

This is because `instanceof` is basically testing the *prototype chain* against the RHS, and there is no such chain.

Comment: For what usecase would I want `instanceof Object` to fail?

Comment: @Bergi perhaps if you wanted to go down a different code path in code you can't change, or if you want to create a custom data structure with prototype chain that gets handled differently to _Object_ but don't want to make the decision until after you have filtered out _Object_ instances? I'm not suggesting these uses will be common.

Answer (score 5):

You can use such an object for a key-value map. Without the prototype chain, you can be sure that things like `.toString()` do not unwittingly exist on the object. That means you can incautiously access properties on it, and you can use the `in` operator instead of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`.

Comment: +1, `in` is a very useful operator and avoiding unexpected positives this way could be exceedingly helpful.