# Difference {} between Object.create({})

Tags: javascript

Sorry, this question has probably a duplicate but the `{}` make it hard to search or nobody ever asked it like that. What is the difference between :

```
var a = {};
```

and

```
var b = Object.create({});
```

Using Google Dev Tool it seems quite similar (even when using `dir(a)`, `dir(b)`)

Comment: I guess you mean `Object.create(null);`?

Comment: do you mean that `Object.create({})`and `Object.create(null)` does exactly the same thing ?

Comment: No, `{}` and `Object.create({});` do nearly the same thing (Object.create({}); creates \__proto__ in \__proto__, which doesn't really make sense to do). `Object.create(null)` creates an empty object literal (just like the two other ones), but without anything on the prototype. https://jsfiddle.net/dyqs7xLb/. It's considered safer to use Object.create(null), especially when using  `for in` loops

Comment: When they use `Object.create({});` they've done something wrong

Comment: @baao are you sure that doing use  ` Object.create({});` is wrong, could you explain me why ? )

Comment: Wrong is a harsh word... :-) Let's say it doesn't make any sense. I'm not sure which bugs it could introduce (if any). But I'm pretty sure they wanted to use the newish `Object.create(null)` and confused that with `Object.create({})`. I don't see the slightest benefit from using that..

Comment: It comes from the Odoo JS code : [https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/boot.js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/boot.js) and they do : `var services = Object.create({});` I shall precise it directly in my question but I thought it was more trivial..

Comment: @snoobdogg Thanks for the link to that source. I'm pretty sure it's a mistake (bug), they probably meant to use `Object.create(null)` (as they did use for `factories`) which [would be actually useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20804241/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object literal `{}` creates an object that has `Object.prototype` as its prototype.

The [`Object.create(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function call creates an object that has `x` as its prototype.

So `Object.create({})` will create an object that has an empty object as its prototype which in turn has `Object.prototype` as its prototype. Which is pretty useless, this should usually be avoided.

Comment: I confirm it is a typo made by the author of the commit, document.create was before something like "document.create({...})